# activate pt:data-tooltip on commandbutton

Tags: primefaces, xhtml, jsf-2.2

i'm using jsf 2.2 primefaces 6.0 and i'm trying to add "pt:data-tooltip" on my commandButton but it seems that this attribute is unknown.I need help to make it acceptable.

Here the xhtml code of all the xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>
<ui:composition template="/facelets/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><i class="ace-icon fa fa-home home-icon"></i> <a
                href="adminHome.jsf">Acceuil</a></li>
            <li class="active">espace Administrateur</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.breadcrumb -->

    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="pageContent">
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:panel header="ajouter Acte Médical">
                <p:messages />
                <p:panelGrid id="pan" columns="3">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Type acte medical *:" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{acteBean.acteMedical.typeActe}" id="input1" 
                        placeholder="Type de l'acte médical" required="true" 
                        requiredMessage="indiquez une valeur">
                        <f:validator validatorId="av" />
                        <p:ajax event="blur" update="button" process="@form"/>
                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:message id="m1" for="input1" />

                    <p:outputLabel value="Plafond *:" />

                    <p:inputNumber id="i1" value="#{acteBean.acteMedical.plafond}"
                        symbol=" DT" symbolPosition="s" placeholder="Plafond total" 
                        decimalSeparator="," thousandSeparator="."
                        disabled="#{not empty acteBean.acteMedical.pourcentage}">
                        <f:ajax event="keyup" render="i2" />
                    </p:inputNumber>
                    <p:message id="m2" for="i1" />
                    <p:outputLabel value="Pourcentage des frais de remboursement *:" />

                    <p:inputNumber id="i2" value="#{acteBean.acteMedical.pourcentage}"
                        placeholder="% des frais de remboursements" symbolPosition="s"
                        symbol="%" disabled="#{not empty acteBean.acteMedical.plafond}">
                        <f:ajax event="keyup" render="i1" />
                    </p:inputNumber>
                    <p:message id="m3" for="i2" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Sauvegarder" id="button" disabled="#{not facesContext.postback or facesContext.validationFailed}"
                        style="background:#6FDC6F;color: #FFFFFF" 
                        styleClass="customStyleButton" action="#{acteBean.doAddActe()}"
                        update="@form:pan">
                        <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Êtes-vous sûr?"
                            icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Actualiser" action="#{acteBean.reset()}" 
                        style="background:#FF0000; color: #FFFFFF"
                        styleClass="customStyleButton" update="@form:pan" />



                    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                        <p:commandButton value="Oui" type="button"
                            styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                        <p:commandButton value="Non" type="button"  
                            styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                    </p:confirmDialog>


                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>

        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Comment: please next time start with a simple testcase...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the 'pt' namespace declaration

```
xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
```

And you are not using the jsf 2.2 namespace declarations for the jsf components either but the older ones